# How to transform a Map to a SortedMap by lambda expression in JAVA8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

For example, I have a class `Student`

```
public class Student{
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public int getAge(){
        return this.age;
    }
}
```

And a class `School`:

```
public class School{
    private Map<String,Student> students=new TreeMap<>();
    //stroe the index of students in the school by key is their names.

    public SortedMap<Integer,Long> countingByAge(){
        return this.students.entrySet().stream().map(s->s.getValue())
               .collect(groupingBy((Student s)->s.getAge(),counting()));
    }
}
```

The countingByAge method ask for return of a `SortedMap<Integer,Long >`, the key is the age of student, value is the number of students per distinct age, i.e. I need to count how many students per age.

I have almost finished the method, but I don't know how to transform the `Map<Integer,Long>` to `SortedMap<Integer,Long>` without `(SortedMap<Integer,Long>)` casting.

Comment: in my opinion you can just cast it. I don't see anything wrong using cast in this scenario.

Comment: @BufBills It is not okay to just cast it.  The Java compiler generates a warning for that, for good reason.  Unchecked casting undermines the compiler's ability to guarantee correct, safe code where generically typed objects are used.

Comment: @VGR: in this case, it isn’t an *unchecked* cast. It’s simply a cast which will fail at runtime as the `Map` returned by the default `grouping` Collector is not a `SortedMap`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`groupingBy(classifier, mapFactory, downstream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-)  and as `mapFactory` pass Supplier returning instance of Map implementing `SortedMap` like `TreeMap::new`

```
public SortedMap<Integer, Long> countingByAge(){
    return  students.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .collect(groupingBy(Student::getAge, TreeMap::new, counting()));
}
```

BTW, as [@Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) [mentioned in comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31248741/how-to-transform-a-map-to-a-sortedmap-by-lamda-expression-in-java8/31249201#comment50495931_31249201) you can simplify

```
map.entrySet()
.stream()
.map(Map.Entry::getValue)
```

with

```
map.values()
.stream()
```

Comment: `entrySet().stream().map(Map.Entry::getValue)` is an unnecessarily complicated way of saying `values().stream()`…

Comment: @Holger I didn't want to change to many things in OP code, but yes, this would be nice simplification.

Comment: you could add it as an alternative, as the answer isn’t that long that it would distract the reader…

Comment: @Holger Done. In the future feel free to edit my answer if you think it can be improved/simplified. I trust your judgement especially about Java-8 questions.